# edit a google spreadsheet and have a pop up box to confirm an email send

Tags: jquery, email, google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet in google docs with a form that is filled in when a new job comes in. I run a script that sends an email to the tech who is assinged the job, so they know a new job is in.
I would like to run a second script on the sheet, that if the assigned tech name is changed, a pop up confirmation box asks if you would like to resend the email.
From reading here I looked at jquery dialog box (which doesn't work properly yet), but I am having problems with the onEdit function and the email.
I only want the edit function to happen on column F (the one with the names). When I tun the script it tells me it has an invalid email address, which to my mind means I have told it to look in the wrong place.
Here is the code:

```
function onEdit() {;
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();                
var sheet1 = ss.getSheets()[0].getActiveCell();
var sheet2 = ss.getSheets()[4];         
function doGet() {
var template = HtmlService
             .createTemplateFromFile('Job confirmation');

var htmlOutput = template.evaluate()
               .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE)
               .setTitle('jQuery UI Dialog - Job confirmation');

return htmlOutput;}

var Customer = sheet1.getRow()[1];
var name = sheet1.getRow()[6]

var emailArray = sheet2.getDataRange().getValues();

for (i=0;i < emailArray.length;i++){
if (name == emailArray[i][1]) {
  var email_address = emailArray[i][1];
}
}                 


var subject = "Job assignment";
var body    = "A new job for " + Customer + " has been assigned to you. Use the GDocs app on your phone, or Follow the link to see the job: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aq612nokMdeOdGVuZklaRkl5TERkc0ZXYlB5WDBadmc&hl=en_US#gid=0";

MailApp.sendEmail(email_address,subject,body);
}
```

If someone can point me in the right direction I would be most grateful

So I followed Serge's advise and couldn't get the pop up to work correctly, so I thought I would just forget the popup in the short term and focus on making the thing work on edit. However, when the script runs, it does the logging and then finishes without going any further.
Transcript:

```
[14-07-07 15:36:10:692 EST] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() [0 seconds]
[14-07-07 15:36:10:693 EST] Spreadsheet.getActiveRange() [0 seconds]
[14-07-07 15:36:10:693 EST] Range.getRow() [0 seconds]
[14-07-07 15:36:10:693 EST] Range.getLastRow() [0 seconds]
[14-07-07 15:36:10:694 EST] Range.getColumn() [0 seconds]
[14-07-07 15:36:10:694 EST] Range.getLastColumn() [0 seconds]
[14-07-07 15:36:10:699 EST] Starting execution
[14-07-07 15:36:10:720 EST] Logger.log([{"range":{"rowStart":43,"rowEnd":43,"columnEnd":6,"columnStart":6},"source":{},"value":"Dan","user":{}}, []]) [0 seconds]
[14-07-07 15:36:10:720 EST] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() [0 seconds]
[14-07-07 15:36:10:793 EST] Spreadsheet.getSheets() [0.073 seconds]
[14-07-07 15:36:10:867 EST] Spreadsheet.getSheets() [0.073 seconds]
[14-07-07 15:36:10:868 EST] Logger.log([Customer row = 43, []]) [0 seconds]
[14-07-07 15:36:10:868 EST] Sheet.getRange([43, 6]) [0 seconds]
[14-07-07 15:36:11:032 EST] Sheet.getDataRange() [0.163 seconds]
[14-07-07 15:36:11:112 EST] Range.getValues() [0.078 seconds]
[14-07-07 15:36:11:112 EST] Range.toString() [0 seconds]
[14-07-07 15:36:11:113 EST] Execution succeeded [0.405 seconds total runtime]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fault in the above code, not withstanding the pop up, which I figured I could do without at the moment.
The code was completing because the logger was giving off the line number as the customer and 'Range' as the name. Because I had added a line in the array, to end if the name didn't match, the script ended without sending.

```
`var Customerrow = Number(e.range.rowStart);`
`var Customer = sheet1.getSheetValues(Customerrow,2,1,1);`
`Logger.log('Customer row = '+Customerrow);`
`var name = sheet1.getSheetValues(Customerrow,6,1,1);`
```

Using `getSheetValues(rowstart,columnstart,number_of_rows,number_of_columns)` solved this problem.

Thanks again Serge for your code.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few errors in this code..., below is a copy that should help you to get it working, I couldn't make it work completely because I'm missing some data about your use case but the structure is there and I commented the most important parts directly in code.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();                
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheets()[0]
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheets()[4];  // this is Sheet number 5, prefer using sheet's name in case you move it accidentally.       
  var column = Number(e.range.columnStart);// e has all the informations about the event source (range, value ... )look at the Logger
  if(column != 6){return};// if not coming from column F then return
  var Customer = Number(e.range.rowStart);// gives you the row number of the edited cell
  Logger.log('Customer row = '+Customer);
  var name = sheet1.getRange(Customer,6);//get value in col F in row being edited

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();// this is how the popup is shown in a SS
  var popup = showHTMLUi; 
  ui.showModalDialog(popup,'confirmation message');// show the popup 

// some value has to be returned from this UI to allow taking a decision about the code below

  var emailArray = sheet2.getDataRange().getValues();// get All emails adresses

  for (i=0;i < emailArray.length;i++){
    if (name == emailArray[i][1]) { // be sure to choose the right index, arrays count from 0 so emailArray[i][1] means column B... is that right ?
      var email_address = emailArray[i][1];
    }
  }                 
  var subject = "Job assignment";
  var body    = "A new job for " + Customer + " has been assigned to you. Use the GDocs app on your phone, or Follow the link to see the job: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aq612nokMdeOdGVuZklaRkl5TERkc0ZXYlB5WDBadmc&hl=en_US#gid=0";

  MailApp.sendEmail(email_address,subject,body);
}  

function showHTMLUi() {// this function has to be separated from the onEdit function
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Job confirmation');
  var htmlOutput = template.evaluate().setTitle('jQuery UI Dialog - Job confirmation');// default mode is 'Native'
  return htmlOutput;
}
```

Comment: Serge, things work well, but I can't get the popup to er pop up. Also you were right I had the wrong index in the array. The pop up works when tested via the web app deployment, but because it doesn't deploy, there is no response and the script completes

Comment: Sorry, I'm on holidays without computer access, only my cellphone.... cannot test nor really help for now.try reposting on specific issue.sorry again.